# SSL with authentication without encryption

Tags: ssl, web-server, lighttpd, curl

Is it possible to setup lighttpd server and curl client so that both the client and the server verify each other's self-signed SSL certificate but the file is downloaded without SSL encryption?

How can I setup this?

Comment: Are you sure that makes sense? CPU load is caused by asymmetric crypto, hardly by the symmetric encryption of the transfer.

Comment: We are running it on relatively weak machine and we observe significant speeds drops during transfers.

Comment: Have you compared the speed drops with encrypted and unencrypted connections? Maybe HTTP digest authentication is the solution for you (avoiding the SSL handshake CPU load). I don't know whether lighttpd supports that, though.

Comment: @Hauke Laging: The speed drops from hundreds to tens of Mb/s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, it's possible to specify the the OpenSSL library not to use any encryption (SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA and similar) but it doesn't make any sense from a security point of view: that would make it wide open to a man-in-the-middle attack.

I checked the lighthttpd documentation and it doesn't seem that you can pass it directly an OpenSSL cyphersuit constant. You might want to try it, though.